# Use for loop with nested if statement in R to populate column from non-NA values in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, na, coalesce

I have 3 columns of data that I'd like to use to populate column D (example below of end result, currently column D is blank).  For each row, columns A-C will have 1 populated value and 2 NA values.  How can I do this?

```
    A   B   C   D
1  'a' NA  NA  'a'
2  NA  'b' NA  'b'
3  NA  'b' NA  'b'
4  NA  NA 'c'  'c'
5  NA  NA 'c'  'c'
6  'a' NA  NA  'a'
7  'a' NA  NA  'a'
8  NA  NA 'c'  'c'
```

I tried the following function and although it didn't error out, it didn't populate my dataset.  I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help

```
pop_D <- function(dataset){
for(i in 1:nrow(dataset)){
    if(!is.na(dataset[i,'A'])){
    dataset[i,'D'] <- dataset[i,'A']
  }else if(!is.na(dataset[i,'B'])){
    dataset[i,'D'] <- dataset[i,'B']
  }else{
    dataset[i,'D'] <- dataset[i,'C']
  }
 }
}
pop_D(ds)
```

Comment: You're missing a `return(dataset)`.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent about 5 hours trying to figure out what was wrong.  That was it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `dft` as your input, you can use `dplyr` and do:

```
dft %>%
  mutate(D = coalesce(A,B,C))
```

which gives:

```
     A    B    C D
1    a <NA> <NA> a
2 <NA>    b <NA> b
3 <NA>    b <NA> b
4 <NA> <NA>    c c
5 <NA> <NA>    c c
6    a <NA> <NA> a
7    a <NA> <NA> a
8 <NA> <NA>    c c
```

---

p.s. I prepared the sample input data by copying from the question as:

```
dft <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "id    A   B   C   D
1  'a' NA  NA  'a'
2  NA  'b' NA  'b'
3  NA  'b' NA  'b'
4  NA  NA 'c'  'c'
5  NA  NA 'c'  'c'
6  'a' NA  NA  'a'
7  'a' NA  NA  'a'
8  NA  NA 'c'  'c'",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dft$id<- NULL
dft$D <- NULL
```

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks.  One issue I found using this code is that I had failed to set the dataframe stringsAsFactors = FALSE.  Once I did it ran great.

Comment: Awesome. Though it's fun to write your own function, most of the stuff is already out there ;) . In case it helped, please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pmax` to do this

```
df1$D <- do.call(pmax, c(df1[1:3], na.rm = TRUE))
df1$D
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "a" "a" "c"
```

---

Or a second option is applying `max.col` on the logical `matrix` for non-NA elements to get the column index, `cbind` with the row index and extract the elements based on these indexes

```
df1[1:3][cbind(1:nrow(df1), max.col(!is.na(df1[1:3]), 'first'))]
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "a" "a" "c"
```

Comment: nice. I need to get more into functions like `pmax` and `max.col`.

Comment: and fair :) ...

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to akrun's answer, if you have a matrix (or a dataframe that you convert with `as.matrix()`) you can just combine all the data and omit all the `NA`'s to create your variable D, i.e.

```
mt<-matrix(c("a",NA,NA,"a",NA,"b",NA,NA,NA,NA,"c",NA),ncol=3) #create test data

cbind(mt,na.omit(c(as.matrix(mt))))
```